# scala sum By Key function

Tags: scala

Given an array as follows:

```
val stats: Array[(Int, (Double, Int))]=Array((4,(2,5)),  (4,(8,4)),  (7,(10,0)),  (1,(1,3)), (4,(7,9)))
```

How can I get the sum of the 1st elements of pairs when grouped by key !!!
For example, for the key value **4**, I've to sum these values **2.0 + 8.0 + 7.0**

```
result = Array((4, 17.0), (7, 10.0), (1, 1.0))
```

I started by doing this but I don't how to continue:

```
stats.groupBy(_._1) mapValues (_.map(_._2)) //....
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
stats.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2._1).sum).toArray
//  Array((4,17.0), (7,10.0), (1,1.0))
```

You're pretty close, you just need to grab `._2._1`, which is `b` in the `(a,(b,c))` object.  And then you can sum those values.